# how to optimize neural network input using GA? (maximizing the input)

Tags: optimization, neural-network, genetic-algorithm

I am new to this field and any help can be useful. I'm currently doing process optimization for furnace operation - in MATLAB. I am trying to relate the process parameters with the efficiency of the heater such as e.g.:

Inputs (Process parameters)

heat gain heater draft pressure excess air Outputs

heater efficiency

I am first training a Neural Network model in order to predict the efficiency from the process parameters. I got good results and for now I am not interested in the performance.

Next I want to optimize (maximize) the input parameter heat gain using Genetic Algorithm. using heat balance,my fitness function (object function) is

heat gain = (Qf/m)*[1-(.5/(21-x1)+.8)*(x2-Ta)] Qf is fired duty excess air = x1 m is mass flow T is fluid temperature = x2 Ta ambient temperature

only excess air is an input in the neural network, other parameters were not used in the network I don't have constrains but I have LB & UB

function y = fitness(x)

```
y = (Qf/m)*[1-(.5/(21-x1)+.8)*(x2-Ta)];
```

end

next i set the number of design variables and their upper and lower bounds:

nvars = 2; % Number of variables LB = [3 280]; % Lower bound UB = [4 310]; % Upper bound

[x,fval] = ga(@fitness_func,nvars,[],[],[],[],LB,UB,@(x));

I still don't know how to fit the network input into the GA (to maximize input)

I hope I've explained the problem in clear way. As I said at the beginning,I am new on this subject and any help is appreciated

Comment: Is the network topology fixed and what kind of compute units (neurons) are you using?

Comment: the network part is done and I used 20 neurons in one layer. so I have 3 inputs, and 1 output.what I need to know how to maximize the first input to the network(heat gain) by using the genetic algorithms.I wrote the script but still did not know how to finish it. Thanks